# Error running "npm run dev" in my Next.js project

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js

npm run dev

> mongoose-auth@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Escritorio\mongoose-auth.next\server\app\page.js'] {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'readlink',
path: 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Escritorio\mongoose-auth\.next\server\app\page.js'
}

I was working normally on my Next.js project with TypeScript and MongoDB, and I closed the terminal to clear the errors. When I ran the 'npm run dev' command again, I encountered this error.